# How to persist pending changes for multiple users

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, persistence

I'm working on enterprise application on Java. For interaction with database I use EJB.

There are many tables in database, and values inside them are editable via web ui. For now when user makes some changes, these changes are immediately written to database.

But I need all changes to be pending (not persisted) until a user press big "Save" button on the web page. At the same time there is a requirement that all changes should be saved across user sessions, so I can't just store them in beans or on client side. All changes should remain even if user reboot his computer or access my application from another device. So I need to persist pending changes somehow.

First solution which I thought about was to create a copy of all editable tables with some prefix like "tmp". When user change something, I will store new value in "tmp_something". When user finally press "Save", I will move his changes to the main "something" table from "tmp_something". To separate records from different users in tmp_ tables all of them will have additional column called "user_id". So for all users I will have to have one copy of my tables.

Actually, I don't like this solution at all! I will have to rewrite a lot of code, create new classes for each new table...

And my question: is there some better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

1.Why don't you try the [Multiton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern). 
Use a Singleton Bean that contains a `Map<Key, Object>`The Singleton will be available application wide, the objects will be accessible by their unique key and it will only be persisted when you explicitly tell it to. I hope this helps

2.I'm not too well versed with the [Java Transaction API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API). but I think it might be another option you can check out.

Regards